# Drawing a cubic line chart using MPAndroid chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I was trying to draw a cubic line graph such as this:

[image]

using the MPAndroid chart library.

I am able to draw the line but not the fill between the X Axis and the line as shown in the picture.
Have gone through library and many SO questions.

Comment: For clarity: in your graph I can see a normal timechart with a smooth curve (sinusoidal). A cubic expression is something else.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein You can check the heading of the graph in the link itself https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart . I just wanted to know how do I get the fill. Can this be done using a line chart or something else

Comment: It isn't featured in the example. I know that it is possible. Not just able to figure the stuff out

Comment: I don't use that library, but I can guess it's some property to set. The documentation should mention that.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted so many times?

Comment: @Anshul you may improve it by upvoting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(vals, null);

dataset.setDrawFilled(true);
```

> [`setDrawFilled(boolean filled)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.6/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineRadarDataSet.html#setDrawFilled(boolean))
>
> Set to true if the `DataSet` should be drawn filled (surface), and not just as a line, disabling this will give great performance boost! default: `false`

You can also control the transparency:

> [`setFillAlpha(int alpha)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.6/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineRadarDataSet.html#setFillAlpha(int))
>
> sets the alpha value (transparency) that is used for filling the line surface (0-255), default: 85

And color:

> [`setFillColor(int color)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.6/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineRadarDataSet.html#setFillColor(int))
>
> sets the color that is used for filling the line surface

Answer (score 11):

1. To remove horizontal grid lines:

   ```
   chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
   ```
2. For cubic lines:

   ```
   dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
   ```
3. To Fill area below line, disable displayed values:

   ```
   dataSet.setDrawFilled(true);
   dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
   ```
4. Set fill color and line color:

   ```
   dataSet.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contex,R.color.pale_green));
   dataSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contex,R.color.pale_green));
   ```
5. Disable transparency (values range 0-255) and disable drawing circles on the main chart line:

   ```
   dataSet.setFillAlpha(255);
   dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
   ```

---

Result:
[image]

---

edit1:
To disable legend and hide description:

```
chart.getDescription().setText("");
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

and:

```
<color name="pale_green">#6BF3AD</color>
```

edit2: To disable right axis:

```
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

edit3: Nearly forgot the last thing:

```
  chart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return String.format("%.2f $",value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Specify the version of the library you are using? dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER); this method is not available for some versions.